# Storyboard still shows 'ghost' tab bar item after tab bar removal

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

In our current project we had a tab bar controller, and every corresponding view had a tab bar controller. Lately we decided to use another navigation approach and we removed the tab bar controller. 
Unfortunately the tab bar items in the views seem to be unremovable in the SB. In the running app they are not visible. We even tried to reconnect them to a tab bar controller, but no avail. Also, they don't show up in the document outline.

Is there anyone who can spread some wisdom how to remove them?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making the bottom bar to none in the attribute inspector of viewcontorller

[image]

Comment: Thanks, thats fine as fix. But I wonder from what the guy is inferring?