# Can't Remove Tab Bar After Deleting Tab Bar Item in Storyboard (Swift 4)

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, xcode9, uitabbaritem

This should be ridiculously simple, but I just can't seem to find the answer.

Assume you start off with a brand new View Controller, and then drag in a Tab Bar Item from the object library (putting it on the bottom of the controller). Then you click on that item in the storyboard and click delete. The item is removed from the storyboard, but the tab bar remains. It no longer appears in the Controller Scene, but it still shows up on the Storyboard as a blank tab bar.

I can't figure out how to get rid of this ghost tab bar. The closest reference i could find to this problem was this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920635/storyboard-still-shows-ghost-tab-bar-item-after-tab-bar-removal), but the version is too different and couldn't get this to work. I know I could just undo these actions, but it is on a project where this was done a long time ago, and I can't figure out when the problem came up.

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks!

[After Adding Tab Bar Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoufW.png)

[After Deleting Tab bar item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDKcm.png)

Comment: It looks like you have deleted the item that was inside the tab bar and not the tab bar itself. If you expand the view item, is the tab bar inside?

Comment: The tab bar isn't inside when expanding the view item, so it looks like it was properly removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please select: Bottom Bar - none

[image]